# How should I implement media queries for Android and iPhone?

Tags: javascript, media-queries

I have three sets of images. One set that i want to use for iPhone 4,5 & iPad and I have two sets of images for Android phones, one high res and one low. **Not sure how to accomplish this.**

I'm struggling to figure out the best way to do this. Can i somehow use one media query for iphone and ipad, since i want to use the same images? Or do I have to check for iPhone 4 and 5 like this

```
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and 
    (max-device-width : 568px) and    (orientation : landscape){
       // iPhone 5, load images.
    } 

    @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5), 
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
    // iPhone 4, load the same images.
    }
```

Can I somehow check if its a android device or apple device? If thats the case, maybe I could have two seperate CSS-files and just load the correct one, and inside the correct CSS-file, i'll load the right images. My project consists of only JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

MediaQueries are powerful, but can only go so far.

The best way that I've found to target specific User Agents is [CssUserAgent.js](http://cssuseragent.org/)

It works like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com), but instead of adding classes for browser functionality, it adds very detailed user-agent classes to the `html` tag.

Comment: WillemLabu - Thanks for the respons. I'll check this out. My first thought was maybe to use the iOS images as non-media queries(just load them as standard) and use media queries for the android images. This may not be possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible. CSS means 'cascading', meaning you can override almost _any_ style if you write a more-strict rule that applies.